# Powershell Циклы

Tags: циклы, powershell, кодогенераторы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать цикл на `powershell` для повторения строк N раз?

И что бы менялось имя при использовании `get-newpass` каждый раз на другое, а не одно и тоже.

Пример:

```
function get-newpass {
    $string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    $chars =@()
    $chars += $string.GetEnumerator()
    $count = 12
    return (Get-Random -InputObject $chars -Count $count) -join ''
}
$ksad = get-newpass

$hiaosd = @"
Hi me Friend $ksad
"@


function cikl {
#повтрить N раз $hiaosd
}
```

Comment: `1..8 | % { "Hi me Friend $(get-newpass)" }`

Answer (score 0):

Если используя функции, то так:

```
$counter = 3
printer($counter)

function printer ($counter){
    for($i=1;$i -le $counter;$i++){
            $print = get-newpass
            Write-Host("Hi me Friend "+$print)
        }
    }
function get-newpass {
    $string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    $chars =@()
    $chars += $string.GetEnumerator()
    $count = 12
    return (Get-Random -InputObject $chars -Count $count) -join ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто циклы:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le 5; $i++) { $i }
$i = 0; while ($i -lt 5) { $i++; $i }
$i = 0; do { $i++; $i } until ($i -ge 5)
foreach ($i in 1..5) { $i }
1..5 | ForEach-Object { $_ }
```

Хотя `ForEach-Object` это не цикл, `break`,`continue`,`return` работают там совсем иначе.
А `Get-Random` и как в вопросе работает. Или так:

```
function test
{
    [char[]]$chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' -split '' -notmatch '^$'
    (Get-Random -InputObject $chars -Count 12) -join ''
}
foreach ($i in 1..5) { test }
```